# question about state and counter in react native

Tags: react-native

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
state = {
    count: 0
  }

}

  render() {

    const increase = () => {
      this.setState({
       count: state.count + 1
      })
    }
    
    const decrease = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: state.count - 1
    })
    }
    return (
   
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.increase}>
     <Text>+</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{state.count}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={decrease}>
        <Text>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
   
    )



  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      alignItems: "center" , 
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
})
```

need help trying to find the error its not working trying to understand state and when and why do we use bind ? and how do you set state and when do you use this? ?? So that is where I am confused that the counter does not work and confused with the this keyword and bind keyword.

Answer (score 0):

For basic React / React-Native function binding syntax / knowledge, you may refer to official documents [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html).

In shorts, for Class Components, all the functions / variables defined outside `redner()` should ues `this.xxx`. It is the syntax which refering the functions / objects within same Class Component.

However, the functions / variables defined inside `render()`, you do not need to use `this.xxx`. Just fine to use `xxx`. All the elements within `render()` will re-render when states changes. So use this approach precisely.

Here is a working example for your code modified.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    }
  }

   increase = () => {
      this.setState({
       count: this.state.count + 1
      })
    }

  render() {

    const decrease = () => {
      this.setState({
        count: this.state.count - 1
      })
    }

    return (
   
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.increase}>
          <Text>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text>{this.state.count}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={decrease}>
          <Text>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      alignItems: "center" , 
      justifyContent: "center"
    }
})
```